# How can i use REST command in my Java code?

Tags: java, ftp

I have been trying to prepare a download manager code for downloading http and ftp file. Unlike http file,I cant set a Set Request Property command . So,if I pause my download,after resuming it starts from the beginning and the file is corrupted.

I have studied the FTP RFC . But the syntax did not help me much.Here is a small segment of my code.

```
if(url.toExternalForm().toLowerCase().startsWith("ftp://"))
        {
            //conn.setRequestProperty("Range","bytes=" + downloaded+ "-");
            int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

            if (contentLength < 1)
            {
                error();
            }
            if (size == -1) 
            {
                size = contentLength;
                statChanged();
            }
            if(path == "")file = new RandomAccessFile("c:/Users/user/Downloads/Rudro/" + getFileName(url), "rw");
            else file = new RandomAccessFile(path+ "/" + getFileName(url), "rw");
            file.seek(downloaded);
            stream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        }
```

Can anyone help me where to put the REST command and how ??

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Side note: you don't compare Strings using ==. == compares object references, not the objects themselves. This will eventually fail and provoke strange bugs. Use `equals` to compare Strings. In this case you can even just use `path.isEmpty()` instead.

Comment: You should consider using an existing library such as [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) or [ftp4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/)